# Database Connection Pool Size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, connection-pool

if you were hitting the ceiling on the max number of connections on your DB, what is peoples thoughts on having a smaller connection pool size than the number of threads * workers.

If you didn't want to scale up the database, is it possible that a smaller pool size could do the job, albeit by having some threads waiting on a connection?

I know you could get checkout timeouts, but what is the likelihood of that and what kind of ratio would be acceptable for threads/connections.

thanks